# Exporting NDVI as TIFF file in Google Earth Engine

Tags: arcmap, shapefile, google-earth-engine, feature-collection

I've calculated NDVI using Sentinel data.  Below is the part of my code. This code exporting TIFF file into my google drive, however, when I load this image into ArcMap and trying to convert this raster into shapefile its not happening. This image is opening into ArcMap, but its "Open attribute table" is not enable. I want to share this NDVI layer with other colleagues, so that, they able to calculate area of my NDVI layer. How can I resolve my problem? I'm new to Google Earth Engine

```
//setting range of my NDVI
var ndviRange1 = 0.344;

// Calculating NDVI

var ndvi1 = img.normalizedDifference(['B8A','B4']).rename('NDVI');
var ndviMask1 = ndvi1.gte(ndviRange1); //geater than

// Updating Mask
var NdviData=ndvi1.updateMask(ndviMask1);

//Exporting this mask
Export.image.toDrive({
      image: NdviData,
      description: 'DGKhanDivCo',
      folder:'DGKhanDivCo',
      scale: 05,
      region: roi,
      fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
      maxPixels: 1e12,
    });
```

Comment: I have tried to reclassify the image in ArcMap however, still not able to convert this tiff file downloaded from GEE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the following way to solve this problem in GEE
**(1)** First Export your GEE NDVI Layer as Raster Tiff in your Google Drive using this code below:

```
 Export.image.toDrive({
      image: NdviData,
      description: 'DGKhanDivCo',
      folder:'DGKhanDivCo',
      scale: 05,
      region: roi,
      fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF', 
      maxPixels: 1e12, 
    });
```

**(2)** Download this Geotiff file from your Google Drive and make a Mosaic (If necessary) in Arc Map. Then Reclassify this raster according to your Bins.

**(3)** Convert this reclassify raster to polygon in Arcmap and then merge the polygons and calculate Area

*In this way you can share Google Earth Engine calculated NDVI as Shapefile layer with your Colleagues.
Any shortcut Idea will be appreciable*